# How does ledger pruning work in Solana?

Tags: core-technology

How far into the past can I still fetch transactions and their data? Where does the data go once pruned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is totally up to the operator of the RPC node being queried.  What value is passed with `--limit-ledger-size` to control the local ledger history and whether a BigTable instance is available and configured to provide deep ledger history